# convert it into short code & explan how?

Tags: shortcode

--> 


         
     

    
        

         
     

    
        

Contact  |  Terms of Service  |  Privacy Policy  |  Careers

Comment: this is not a "do my work for me" site :(

Answer (score 3):

A function can be created that generates the output, then that function can be tied to a shortcode using the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API):

```
/**
 * Returns --> Contact  |  Terms of Service  |  Privacy Policy  |  Careers
 *
 * @parm array $atts 
 * @return string 
 */
function wpse241695_arrow_contact_terms_of_service_privacy_policy_careers( $atts ) {
    return '--&gt; Contact &nbsp;|&nbsp; Terms of Service &nbsp;|&nbsp;' .
           ' Privacy Policy &nbsp;|&nbsp; Careers';
}

// Wire up a handy shortcode to output the string.
// Usage: [arrow_contact_terms_of_service_privacy_policy_careers]
add_shortcode( 'arrow_contact_terms_of_service_privacy_policy_careers', 
'wpse241695_arrow_contact_terms_of_service_privacy_policy_careers' );
```

Comment: it's a html code & i put it in word press how to convert it in short code

Comment: how to convert any html in short code this is my question